# Solving polynomial equations takes infinit time

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I need to solve an polynimial equation, but when i try to use Solve or NSolve in mathematica, its cant find the solution in appropriate time (i interrupted calculation after 5 hour left).
The equations is:

```
Remove["Global`*"];
g = 9.8;
C1 = 3.6;
C2 = 0.25;
C3 = 666;
C4 = 2;
c = -36;
e = 0.86;
P0 = 24.44;
h0 = 0.1;

h = h0*(1 + C3*P^C4);
NSolve[{P/P0 == ((1 - e*(1 - h/e))/(1 - e))^((2 + c)/3)/(1 - h/e)^4.65}, {P}]
```

Maybe my computer is too weak or I'm using the wrong method?

Comment: I should check the code before publication, I just tried to move only part that was a problem, I corrected value for x0
I do not quite understand "Also using the dependent variable dP in the RHS of h in the wrong way." - I can express from the first equation the variable P or h and make a single equation, but the result is the same. I apologize if I do not understand some obvious things I have enough experience in dealing with mathematics

Comment: @Nasser: NDsolve? Unless the post changed, that's not being used. OP: Nasser's points are spot-on - if this is some kind of HW problem, please specify such, and perhaps add some context of the over-arching problem. The MM solvers are not magic machines, you might need to 'help' them. Hint: try plotting your function with P around 0.02368.

Comment: @Nasser Wow, thanks very much, It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, try this to see if works for you. Made a function in `P` (wish you used lowerLetterCase) and plotted it. For some values of `P`, the function is complex valued.

One can see the roots at around 0 and .1. Hence use FindRoot to pick them up.

```
Clear[g, C1, C2, C3, C4, c, e, P0, h0, exp, P]
parms = {g -> 9.8, C1 -> 3.6, C2 -> 0.25, C3 -> 666, C4 -> 2, c -> -36, e -> 0.86, 
        P0 -> 24.44, h0 -> 0.1, exp -> 4.65};
h = h0*(1 + C3*P^C4);
f[P_?NumericQ] := P/P0 - ((1 - e*(1 - h/e))/(1 - e))^((2 + c)/3)/(1 - h/e)^exp;
(*verify*)
Simplify[f[P] /. parms]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not a nice looking function in P. If you can simply it a little it will help. You can see the numerator on the second term is almost zero. The limit of the second term as `P->0` is `0.0039`, so may be you can simplify this whole function to a linear function (straight line) in P around zero.

Here is a plot of `f[P]`

```
Plot[Re[f[P] /. parms], {P, -.25, .25}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Im[f[P] /. parms], {P, -.25, .25}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

use `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot[(f[P] /. parms) == 0, {P, .01}]
(* {P -> 0.0236849} *)

FindRoot[(f[P] /. parms) == 0, {P, .11}]
(* {P -> -0.0256356 + 0.0197882 I} *)

FindRoot[(f[P] /. parms) == 0, {P, -.11}]
(* {P -> 0.0236849 + 1.34501*10^-27 I}  *)
```

may be someone will see a better way to handle this.